# Does Kali Purusha get Moksha in the end?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, kali-yuga, kali

I know that Time is cyclical in Hindu mythology. So, does *Kali-Purusha (कलि-पुरुष)* (the personification of the demon after whom Kali Yuga is named) get Moksha after the end of Kaliyuga? And if so, who gives it to him?

Comment: question unclear. Kali or Kala? You use 'him'. Him would imply Kala. Kali would be 'her'. First sentence unclear also.

Comment: I mean the demon Kali, the one after whom Kali Yuga is named.

Comment: You may also take the kali demon is the personification of the unrighteousness. KALI (कलि-पुरुष), itself being the product of 'Krodha (क्रोध)* - it's father, and *Himsa (हिंसा)* - it's mother, *durukti (दुरुक्ति)* - it's consort and/or sibling. Thus, metaphorically delineating the fact that wherever there is anger and violence, there is born unjust, unruly, confusion and suffering along with bad words and inauspiciousness.